# select all except for a specific column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with more than 20 columns, I want to get all columns except for one which I'll use in a conditional expression.

```
SELECT s.* (BUT NOT column1), 
   CASE WHEN column1 is null THEN 1 ELSE 2 END AS column1 
from tb_sample s;
```

Can I achieve it in postgresql given the logic above?

Comment: No, select what fields you want specifically

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1957/sql-select-all-columns-except-some

Comment: Every other possible solution will be more complex then just specifying all desired columns.

Comment: Google BigQuery and Snowflake  supports this . BigQuery`SELECT * EXCEPT(col1) FROM t1` and Snowflake `SELECT * EXCLUDE (col1, col2) FROM t1`. But neither syntax is supported  on postgres 15 (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-select-lists.html)

Answer (score 1):

It may not be ideal, but you can use information_schema to get the columns and use the column to exclude in the where clause.

That gives you a list of all the column names you DO want, which you can copy/paste into your select query:

```
select textcat(column_name, ',')
from information_schema.columns
where table_name ='table_name' and column_name !='column_to_exclude';
```

Comment: I like this, if only there was a way to put this into a select statement, instead of copying and pasting